# Wordpress Media Uploader custom Javascript not working

Tags: custom-field, admin, uploads, media

I encountered a strange problem with my JavaScript (jQuery) when trying to modify the behavior of my Media Uploader in Wordpress 3.5

[image: Image filter selector]

This was my JQuery:

```
$('.attachment-filters').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'uploaded'){
        alert("Uploaded images selected");
    } else {
        alert("Other option selected");
    }
});
```

And this was the part of the media uploader i wanted to react to:

```
<select class="attachment-filters">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All media items</option>
    <option value="uploaded">Uploaded to this page</option>
    <option value="image">Images</option>
    <option value="audio">Audio</option>
    <option value="video">Video</option>
</select>
```

To my big frustration this worked perfectly in a [JS fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohenrik/qh34U/), however it failed miserably in my wordpress admin screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to simply wrap my JQuery in a function like this:

```
$('#wpcontent').ajaxStop(function() {

    $('.attachment-filters').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'uploaded'){
            alert("Uploaded images selected");
        } else {
            alert("Other option selected");
        }
    });

});
```